# How to pass an argument on dynamic asp button EventHandler

Tags: asp.net

Good day  i want to pass a value to a onclick button method :

This is my dynamically created button :

```
string Code = //Some value
Button button = new Button();
button.ID = "Start";
button.Click +=new EventHandler(button_Click);
button.CommandArgument = Code;
Page.Controls.Add(button);
```

this my event method :

```
 void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string code = //Put the value in code 
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One widely used approach is to save such values in a server accessible controls or variable.

In concrete words:

If you want to pass the dynamic value from client side, use an ASP:HiddenField, set its value using JavaScript and access in the server code

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hfMyArgument" value="" />
```

you can use the value on server side

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string code = hfMyArgument.value.trim();
}
```

Create and use a session variable while creating the button

```
Session["MyArgument"] = "argument value";
Session["MySecondArgument"] = 143523;
```

to use these values on server side code C#

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string code = Convert.toString(Session["MyArgument"]).trim();
}
```

Comment: my pleasure, and thanks for marking my answer helpful.
if you don't need to take the argument from the client side and need to use something like global variable then session is a better approach, as you don't need to change the asp code to add the hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using the `CommandArgument` property of button, you can access this property in `OnCommand` event of this button. [ But NOT in OnClick ]

So, define an event handler for `OnCommand` event as:

```
button.Command += new CommandEventHandler(button_Command);
```

And in your event handler access the `CommandArgument` as:

```
void button_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
 {
     string _code = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: ive tried  this but when i click the button it posts back.and the page is refreshed the event is not fired.

Comment: Make sure you create the controls every time you  postback. The code creating the controls should not be inside(!IsPostBack) condition. And postback will happen. Do you want to avoid it ??